# Flutter Firebase) I want to know how to delete old files on Storage

Tags: android, ios, node.js, firebase, flutter

I'm creating a real-time chat and I have the ability to upload files from the chat.
For storage management, I want to remove the file from Storage a month after uploading it.
Can this be implemented on Flutter?
Or should I use Firebase Functions?

I don't know yet because I'm new to node.js and firebase functions.  Do you happen to have an example or a document similar to this?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds feasible in both of those, especially if your store the creation timestamp of each file in its [metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/file-metadata).

In the client you can for every user to [list their own files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/list-files) through the API, and then delete the files that are older than your threshold.

You can also do this on a server, like in Cloud Functions, but then do the same across all users in one go.